# Regular expression to match one of two characters

Tags: c#, console

What regular expression can I use to make sure input matches either a character 'a' or character 'x'.

I have tried the following but this doesn't work as I had hoped.

```
char option;

Console.WriteLine("Please make your option");
for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(options[i]);

}
option = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
while (option != 'a' || option != 'x')
{
    Console.WriteLine("'a' or 'x' please!!");
    option = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

What I want is for one of the two characters to be accepted only...as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No regex is needed, you have logic error here, you need to use `&&` (AND) logic operator instead of `||` (OR) in your while loop:

```
while (option != 'a' && option != 'x')
```

Answer (score 8):

```
   Regex.IsMatch(input, "[ax]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

will match a,x,A,X

Answer (score 4):

`a + x` in rational language, `(a | x)` or [ax] in almost every regexp system.